# How to use vars in ansible roles

Tags: ansible, yaml

I want to create a ansible role to add user with ssh_keys

```
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── playbooks
│   └── add_user.yml
└── roles
    └── add-user
        ├── files
        │   ├── ansible.pub
        │   ├── dhirendra.pub
        │   ├── nitigyas.pub
        │   └── vinayaks.pub
        ├── tasks
        │   └── main.yml
        └── vars
            └── main.yml
```

tasks/main.yml file is :

```
---
- name: AddUser in the server
  user: 
   name: ansible
   password: $6$sHQAZJ32E$ujHauabN7ZTbOQ/zhT5899EIaFErOecXYvTEyhekexy4dydsAXTGdUpaB8M4fQf2UGpZgX/Zg2Uv6areeuv/r0
   comment: Ansible Configuration Mgmt
   shell: /bin/bash

- name: Add SSH key to users home direcotory
  authorized_key: 
   user: "{{ item.name }}"
   key: "{{ item.file }}"
   state: present
  with_items: 
   - ssh_vars
...
```

vars/main.yml file is:

```
---
ssh_vars:    
 - { name: "ansible" , file: 'ansible.pub' }
```

while i run this roles I get following error

```
PLAY [backend1.greengst.com] *************************************************************************************************************

TASK [add-user : AddUser in the server] **************************************************************************************************
ok: [backend1.greengst.com]

TASK [add-user : Add SSH key to users home direcotory] ***********************************************************************************
fatal: [backend1.greengst.com]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'ansible.vars.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'name'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/roles/add-user/tasks/main.yml': line 9, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Add SSH key to users home direcotory\n  ^ here\n"}
Debugger invoked
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is with the way you use `with_items`: bare variables are unsupported for quite a while already.

Correct your loop like this: `with_items: "{{ ssh_vars }}"`